# How to sort and get minimum start date (XSLT)

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I want to sort xml and get minimum start date (delete other) by using xslt

This is my xml

```
<name>
    <name>
        <firstName>Huio</firstName>
        <lastName>Kuyoshitu</lastName>
        <detail>
            <action>P</action>
            <userId>0902</userId>
            <startDate>2019-01-01T00:00:00.000</startDate>
            <endDate>2030-12-31T00:00:00.000</endDate>
        </detail>
        <detail>
            <action>P</action>
            <userId>0902</userId>
            <startDate>1990-01-01T00:00:00.000</startDate>
            <endDate>1999-12-31T00:00:00.000</endDate>
        </detail>
    </name>
</name>
```

I want to get detail which has minimum startdate(1990-01-01T00:00:00.000).

This is expected xml

```
<name>
    <name>
        <firstName>Huio</firstName>
        <lastName>Kuyoshitu</lastName>
        <detail>
            <action>P</action>
            <userId>0902</userId>
            <startDate>1990-01-01T00:00:00.000</startDate>
            <endDate>1999-12-31T00:00:00.000</endDate>
        </detail>
    </name>
</name>
```

I tried this code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="name/name/detail" group-by="userId">
            <xsl:sort select='startDate' order="ascending" />
            <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                <xsl:sort select='startDate' order="ascending" />
                <xsl:if test="position()=1">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but firstName and lastName Tag disappear.

Like this https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/93dFepA

Comment: Why are you grouping and sorting if you only want to identify a minimum? And why do you tag the question as XSLT 1.0 and 2.0, use `version="1.0"` in your code but then demonstrate your problem with a tool supporting XSLT 3.0?

Comment: I want minimum start date in detail and delete other details. I use xslt with xslt1.0

Comment: Then why do you keep tagging your questions as `xslt-2.0`?? An XSLT 1.0 solution will be fundamentally different from one that can use XSLT 2.0 or higher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XSLT 2 and later with the XPath 2 `min` function on `xs:dateTime` sequences reduce the task to

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

<xsl:template match="name/name">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates 
          select="let $min-date := min(detail/startDate/xs:dateTime(.))
                  return node()[not(self::detail) or self::detail[xs:dateTime(startDate) = $min-date]]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/93dFepA/1

Comment: Thank you so much. How's about xslt version1.0? Can I use xslt with version1.0?